# Python threading.Lock does not work in for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and i have this simple code:

```
def f(ID, N):
    # global lock
    if ID == 2:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if ID == 1:
        lock.acquire()
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'{N}: {time.ctime(time.time())} \n')
        print(f"{i}: lock.locked() = {lock.locked()} \n")
        time.sleep(1)
        if i == 2 and ID == 1:
            lock.release()

t = time.time()
class myThread2 (threading.Thread): 
   def __init__(self, threadID, threadname):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = threadname
   def run(self):
       f(self.threadID, self.name)
       print(f'{self.name} finished')

lock = threading.Lock()

# Create new threads objects          
thread1 = myThread2(1, "Thread-1")
thread2 = myThread2(2, "Thread-2")

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

for i in range(5):
    print(f'\t\t\t main programm: {time.ctime(time.time())} \n')
    time.sleep(1)

# thread1.join()
# thread2.join()
print(time.time()-t)
```

And the output is:

```
Thread-1: Thu Sep 27 15:04:29 2018 
             main programm: Thu Sep 27 15:04:29 2018 


0: lock.locked() = True 

Thread-2: Thu Sep 27 15:04:29 2018 

0: lock.locked() = True 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 15:04:30 2018 
Thread-1: Thu Sep 27 15:04:30 2018 


1: lock.locked() = True 

Thread-2: Thu Sep 27 15:04:31 2018 

1: lock.locked() = True 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 15:04:31 2018 
Thread-1: Thu Sep 27 15:04:31 2018 


2: lock.locked() = True 

Thread-2: Thu Sep 27 15:04:32 2018 

2: lock.locked() = True 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 15:04:32 2018 
Thread-1: Thu Sep 27 15:04:32 2018 


3: lock.locked() = False 

Thread-2: Thu Sep 27 15:04:33 2018 

3: lock.locked() = False 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 15:04:33 2018 
Thread-1: Thu Sep 27 15:04:33 2018 


4: lock.locked() = False 

Thread-2: Thu Sep 27 15:04:34 2018 

4: lock.locked() = False 

5.130102634429932Thread-1 finished

>>> Thread-2 finished
```

So my question is the following: Why does lock.acquire() doesnt prevent thread2 from beeing executed till i = 2 and lock.release() command in the f function? I want that it executes the first 3 loops for thread1, and only after that thread2 enters the for loop. But they thread2 enters the for loop after the time.sleep(0.5) immidiately. Why is that? In the output lock.locked() = True after thread1 anters the for loop, but it doesn't have any effect on thread2. Where is the mistake, can you help me?

Comment: you're doing lock.acquire() only on thread 1. When ID==1. To "block" a thread, you have to call lock.acquire() twice. Then the second thread will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Lock, current_thread

lock = Lock()

def fu():
    lock.acquire()

    for i in range(5):
        print('Hello from ' + current_thread().name)

        if i == 3:
            lock.release()
            break


t1 = Thread(target=fu, daemon=True)
t2 = Thread(target=fu, daemon=True)

t1.start()
t2.start()

time.sleep(5)
```

This is a simplier example of what you have but it works (except controlling specificaly which thread goes 1st).

Comment: Hey, it didnt work. It gave me an exception. I changed if i == 2: to if i == 2 and lock.locked() == True:. It gives the same output output as before. But your first advice worked! two lock.acquire(), but still just one lock.release(). I just totally dont understand why it works.

Comment: Hey! I changed my answer to a simplier example which will do what you want except guaranteeing which thread locks the lock 1st. Again, you really don't need doing that. The idea is to limit the amount of threads to execute a certain peace of code instead of controlling specifically which thread executes it. To control this sort of things, you'll need a more complicated code.

Comment: Hey, this is the output from your example:                                                                       Hello from Thread-3
Hello from Thread-3
Hello from Thread-3
Hello from Thread-3
Hello from Thread-4
Hello from Thread-4
Hello from Thread-4
Hello from Thread-4
It is not what i want to achieve. In your example t1 runs through the for-loop till the break command, and only after that  t2 starts running through the loop. But i wanted that thread2 starts to tun through the for loop after thread1 finishes its third iteration (after i = 2), and then both threads run simultaniously

Comment: Just remove the break line then (break makes the thread to stop cycling in the for() loop)

Comment: No problem. Thank you for the question. Can you just accept the answer so this topic is closed?

Comment: yes of course, but i just came up with another one :) i posted the code below

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. this is the code:

```
def f(ID, N):
    # global lock
    if ID == 2:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        lock.acquire()
        lock.acquire()
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'{N}: {time.ctime(time.time())} \n')
        print(f"{i}: lock.locked() = {lock.locked()} \n")
        time.sleep(1)
        if i == 2 and lock.locked() == True:
            lock.release()
```

It works. thread2 enters the for-loop after thread1 finishes the i = 2. In the end it is lock.locked() = False. So this is the result i wanted, i just totally dont get why it works.

Comment: Man.. I see that "lock" logic knowlegde is missing here :) Basically, a Lock is, as the name suggests, a lock which will close when you call acquire() and open when you call release(). The Lock is initiated as opened. So when one of the threads reaches 1st the acquire() line, it closes the lock and as so no more thread can lock it again. All the threads that will try to acquire() a locked lock will stay there forever until the 1st thread that locked the lock open it. Basically, the lock guarantees that the piece of code after acquire() is being executed by one thread only.

Comment: yes , i understand that. but why do i need a second lock.acquire() command then? I thought that the first lock.acquire() command blocks  thread2. and when thread1 reaches i = 2 in the for-loop, the commynd release.lock() allows  thread2 to enter the for-loop and run the for-loop. so why do i need a second lock.acquire() right after the first lock.acquire()?

Comment: you don't need it! What is probably happening is: Thread2 enters f() 1st. So it locks the lock (1st acquire) and then blocks on the second acquire. Then, the other thread enters f(), and goes straight to the loop. Does the looping, unlocks the lock, which releases the Thread2. Actually if the first thread to reach f() is Thread1, the same will happen because you're only blocking the 2nd thread.

Comment: well, it works now with only one command lock.acquire(). still confused

Comment: I've modified my other answer. Please check it and see if you can understand it. It's a simplier example of what you have.. so it might be easier to understand what's happening. Try to play with it and change something too

Comment: hey thanks for your help. can you help with another lock question? I made a new code example.

Answer (score 0):

now it works with only one lock.acquire():

```
def f(ID, N):
    # global lock
    if ID == 2:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    lock.acquire()
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'''{N}:  {time.ctime(time.time())}  
              {i}:  lock.locked() = {lock.locked()}
              current thread = {threading.current_thread()} \n\n''')
        time.sleep(1)
        if i == 2 and lock.locked() == True:
            lock.release()
            print(f'''{N}:  {time.ctime(time.time())}  
            {i}:  lock.locked() = {lock.locked()}
            current thread = {threading.current_thread()} \n\n''')
```

i get this output then:

```
Thread-1:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:52 2018  
              0:  lock.locked() = True
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-1, started 5880)> 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 20:13:52 2018 


Thread-1:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:53 2018  
              1:  lock.locked() = True
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-1, started 5880)> 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 20:13:53 2018 


Thread-1:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:54 2018  
              2:  lock.locked() = True
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-1, started 5880)> 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 20:13:54 2018 


Thread-2:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:55 2018  
              0:  lock.locked() = True
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-2, started 2004)> 

Thread-1:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:55 2018  
            2:  lock.locked() = False
            current thread = <myThread2(Thread-1, started 5880)> 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 20:13:55 2018 



Thread-1:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:55 2018  
              3:  lock.locked() = True
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-1, started 5880)> 


Thread-2:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:56 2018  
              1:  lock.locked() = True
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-2, started 2004)> 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 20:13:56 2018 
Thread-1:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:56 2018  
              4:  lock.locked() = True
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-1, started 5880)> 




Thread-2:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:57 2018  
              2:  lock.locked() = True
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-2, started 2004)> 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 20:13:57 2018 
Thread-1 finished


Thread-2:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:58 2018  
            2:  lock.locked() = False
            current thread = <myThread2(Thread-2, started 2004)> 

             main programm: Thu Sep 27 20:13:58 2018 


Thread-2:  Thu Sep 27 20:13:59 2018  
              3:  lock.locked() = False
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-2, started 2004)> 


Thread-2:  Thu Sep 27 20:14:00 2018  
              4:  lock.locked() = False
              current thread = <myThread2(Thread-2, started 2004)> 


Thread-2 finished
8.259018182754517
lock.locked() = False
```

It gives the desired output, but still confuses me. now thread2 acquires the lock after thread1 releases it, so how can thread1 continue to run simultaniously with thread2? I still dont understand why the version i wrote in the question doesnt give this output.

Comment: "how can thread1 continue to run simultaniously with thread2?" - it continues to run (thread1) because it's not trying to call lock.acquire() again.

Comment: The very 1st question you posted doesnt work as you want because the lock (which is open) is acquired only by thread with ID==1. Since the lock is opened, thread1 proceeds after locking it, and thread 2 doesnt try to acquire the Lock. So it's not being stopped too

Comment: thank you. would it be too much if i ask you to look at the other code i posted?

Answer (score 0):

this is the code:

```
t = time.time()
def f1(a,b):
    lock2.acquire()
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'\t {i} \t {a+b} \t THREAD1 \t {time.ctime(time.time())} \n')
        time.sleep(1)
    lock2.release()

def f2(a,b):
    lock2.acquire()
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'\t {i**2} \t {a+b} \t THREAD2 \t {time.ctime(time.time())} \n')
        time.sleep(1)
    lock2.release()

class myThread3 (threading.Thread): # create class of threads
   def __init__(self, ID, NAME, f, x, y):
      super().__init__(target = f, name = NAME, args = (x,y,)) # kein self in super()!!!
      # threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=None, target = f, name = NAME, args = (x,y,))
      self.threadID = ID

lock2 = threading.Lock()

# Create new threading.Thread objects         
t1 = myThread3(101, "Threaddd-1", f1, 5, 5)
t2 = myThread3(102, "Threaddd-2", f2, 1, 1)

# Start new Threads
t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

and this is the output:

```
 0   10      THREAD1     Thu Sep 27 21:19:36 2018 

 1   10      THREAD1     Thu Sep 27 21:19:37 2018 

 2   10      THREAD1     Thu Sep 27 21:19:38 2018 

 3   10      THREAD1     Thu Sep 27 21:19:39 2018 

 4   10      THREAD1     Thu Sep 27 21:19:40 2018 

 0   2   THREAD2     Thu Sep 27 21:19:41 2018 

 1   2   THREAD2     Thu Sep 27 21:19:42 2018 

 4   2   THREAD2     Thu Sep 27 21:19:43 2018 

 9   2   THREAD2     Thu Sep 27 21:19:44 2018 

 16      2   THREAD2     Thu Sep 27 21:19:45 2018
```

so what i dont understand, why are t1 and t2 not running simultaniously??? t1 calls f1 and not f2. t2 calls f2 and not f1. they dont share variables. so the locks should not have any effect, right??? why is t2 blocked till t1 releases the lock?

Comment: They do share variables, ofc. If you want something that does not share variables, use multiprocessing instead. Thread != Process and a quick search on google can explain why

Comment: Close the issue xD